# GitHub - File change display code block has existed in the target branch (master branch)

Tags: git, github

I want to merge `feature` branch to master branch, conflict happen so I merge `master` to `feature` branch.

But when I check on file change tab, it all display code block which has existed in `master` branch (may be other people merged to master while I was developing my `feature`).

Can anybody explain for me that why file change not only show my code also so have code block of other people?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody explain for me that why file change not only show my code also so have code block of other people.

Because there was concurrent deliveries to `master` while you were developing `feature`.
You should not merge `master` back to your branch.
You should simply:

- either resolve the merge conflicts when merging your branch `feature` to `master`
- or, if you are the only one working on `feature`, replay locally `feature` on top of `master`, resolve conflicts locally, then merge again to `master` (the merge will then be trivial)

The second case would be:

```
git switch master
git pull

git switch feature
git rebase master

# resolve conflicts

git switch master
git merge feature
```

Comment: Double merge to wrap up?

Comment: @eftshift0 typo (too much coffee?) I have edited the answer.